# Standard Draw Java window

Tags: java, stddraw

I am having a problem with StdDraw and resizing the window so points appear. I have a Point class with a draw() method

```
/**
* Draws this point to standard draw.
*/
public void draw() {
    /* DO NOT MODIFY */
    StdDraw.point(x, y);
}
```

Then in a tester class I have

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Point p = new Point(3, 4);
    StdDraw.setXscale(0, 10);
    StdDraw.setYscale(0, 10);
    p.draw();
}
```

When I run this, I get two windows that pop up, both with nothing in them. I assume one is a window from the Point class, plotting the point at (3,4) on a coordinate plane that has not been resized, and the other window is the resized window from the tester class with no points on it. Am I missing something here? How can I get this to run in one window without modifying the Point class?

Comment: Please read the documentation of StdDraw, then chekcout some examples, tutorials. You can handle that yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have read through the documentation, looked at examples, and tutorials. The difference with all of the examples I have seen is that the main method is in the same class as the point being drawn. So if I put my main method in my Point class then yes, I can make it work. But as soon as I make a separate class for main, I get two draw windows popping up. Maybe I've been looking at it for too long and I'm missing something small, but any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

OK after a suggestion that I may have two JVM's running, the answer was revealed! The problem was that I had both algs4.jar and stdlib.jar in my classpath variable. I removed algs4.jar from the classpath and it worked. So check your classpath variables if you're running into a similar issue!